# Debugging software that can check for NULL dereferences?

Tags: c++, debugging

Is there software smart enough to figure out that you got a pointer from somewhere and the returned pointer could be NULL and no where in the block do you do:

```
ptr = getSomeDataThatCouldReturnNULLAt(-1);
```

...

```
if(ptr)
{
   //code
}
```

or

```
if(!ptr)
{
   return;
}
```

Is there software that can let  you know all the places where this might not be checked?

Thanks

Checking for runtime problems.

Comment: Are you talking about run time, or compile time static analysis? For instance, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ff549179.

Comment: Pretty much every pointer in your program could be NULL at one point or another.

Comment: Debuggers don't do analysis, you're probably looking for a static analysis tool. Many good ones for CPP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the better way to code this would be as follows :

```
s32 getSomeDataThatCouldReturnNULLAt( s32 intParam, void **inputPointer);
```

and then in your function where you want to invoke this function :

```
s32 returnValue = 0 ;
void * ptr = NULL ; 

if((returnValue = getSomeDataThatCouldReturnNULLAt( -1, &ptr) ) != ERROR ||
  ptr ==NULL )
   return returnValue;
```

`returnValue` can indicate the error that occured in your `getSomeDataThatCouldReturnNULLAt`

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  The OP is looking for code analysis tools, not asking how to use error codes and out parameters.

Comment: As you already commented on the question(`pretty much every pointer in your program could be NULL`) , it makes more sense to write a better code which would be less error prone than spending countless hours debugging later on. I would take your -1 and would still stick to the recommendations i have in the answer. Regards,-J

Comment: Well if we're taking that route then I would argue that error codes and out parameters are not a great solution either. You're simply replacing one check with another.  I am leery of any code that calls `operator new`, and if you absolutely must return a pointer from a function then return a smart pointer.

Comment: error codes can be passed all the way to client if you have a pretty complex system. Error codes help to debug issues especially in the escalated situations where your box is miss-behaving at the customer site. So writing a better code is always better idea than trying to come up with something quick.

Comment: I understand what error codes are (I work on a complex medical device that uses error codes *everywhere*).  Exceptions exist in C++ as well.  They can be tricky, but I am not a fan of following every function call with `if(ret_code != OK) { do_something(); return; }`.  Still has nothing to do with static code analysis, and you're still passing raw pointers around when you don't need to.

Comment: @JayD: Exceptions are superior to error codes in the general case, this is an old and done argument. Anyway, this is nothing to do with better or worse code, it has to do with static correctness checking. Ideally your language would have a strong enough type system to this, but no mainstream language does (ATS comes to mind as an existing implementation, though). So the next route is to have software extract these constraints automatically on top of C++, which is what Milo is asking for help on.